# Cumulative sum for months that do and dont exist in a Snowflake table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions, cumulative-sum

So I have some data as follows:

```
ID   action_date     data
001   2021-01-20     jams
002   2021-01-23   orange
003   2021-01-19   banana
001   2021-04-11   pineap
002   2021-03-01    grape
004   2021-03-01    apple
```

Using this data, I would like to make a table of cumulative sums of the entries in the above table.

What I mean by this is for every month, I would like to determine each user's history. If no data exists for the user in that month, the previous month's data is used.

**I would like to have the unique id effectively be the ID of a user and the month.**

The following variables be created:

1. action_taken_this_month - Does the ID appear this month in the original table? Identified if the `action_date` appears in the month.
2. total_actions - How many times did the ID appear in the table, exclusive of the current month.
3. most_recent_data - What was the most recent `data` value. exclusive of the current month.

Final output looks as follows:

```
ID    month_end   action_taken_this_month     total_actions most_recent_data
001  2021-01-31                         1                 0               NA
001  2021-02-28                         0                 1             jams
001  2021-03-31                         0                 1             jams
001  2021-04-30                         1                 1             jams
002  2021-01-31                         1                 0               NA
002  2021-02-28                         0                 1           orange
002  2021-03-31                         1                 1           orange
002  2021-04-30                         0                 2            grape
003  2021-01-31                         1                 1               NA
003  2021-02-28                         0                 1           banana
003  2021-03-31                         0                 1           banana
003  2021-04-30                         0                 1           banana
004  2021-03-31                         1                 1               NA
004  2021-04-30                         0                 1            apple
```

Comment: You need a table or CTE that lists the months so you can use that as the driving table and left join your data to it.  That's the only way to get rows for months which had no activity

Comment: but then how would i track historics if there are severla joins happening? @Kurt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a request that's overly complicated by arbitrary rules, but I'm going to give you an answer that's 90% there.

It uses cross joins to generate the combinations with no data, and a UDF to generate the missing months. Then window functions to get the desired values:

```sql
with data as (
    select x[4]::string id, x[5]::date action_date, x[6]::string data
    from (
    select split(value, ' ') x
    from table(split_to_table(
$$    001 2021-01-20 jams
    002 2021-01-23 orange
    003 2021-01-19 banana
    001 2021-04-11 pineap
    002 2021-03-01 grape
    004 2021-03-01 apple$$, '\n'
)))), range_months as (
    select date_trunc(month, min(action_date)) since, max(action_date) until
    from data
), all_months as (
    select value::date m
    from range_months, table(flatten(list_months_between(since, until)))
), all_ids as (
    select distinct id
    from data
), all_crossed as (
    select *
    from all_months, all_ids
), left_joined as (
    select m, a.id, data, b.action_date action_date
    from all_crossed a
    left join data b
    on a.id=b.id
    and date_trunc(month, b.action_date)=a.m
), almost_there as (
    select m, id, count(action_date) action_taken_this_month, any_value(data) recent_data
        , lag(action_taken_this_month) over(partition by id order by m) previous_action_taken_this_month
    from left_joined
    group by 1, 2
)

select id, last_day(m) month_end
    , action_taken_this_month
    , ifnull(sum(previous_action_taken_this_month) over(partition by id order by m), 0) total_actions
    , lag(recent_data, 1) over(partition by id order by m) most_recent_data
from almost_there
order by 1, month_end
```

I wrote the UDF to generate a list of months in Python, but you can rewrite in your favorite language if desired:

```sql
create or replace function list_months_between(since date, until date)
returns array
language python
runtime_version='3.8'
packages=('pandas')
handler = 'x'
as 
$$
import pandas as pd
def x(since, until):
    return pd.date_range(since, until, freq='MS').strftime("%Y-%m-%d").tolist()
$$
;

select list_months_between('2020-01-01', '2020-03-10');
```

At the end of this series of sub-queries, we get results 90% like desired:

[image]

After all this work, I hope you can take this queries and add an extra join to replace some of the nulls on `most_recent_data` with the last lookup value.